# xml DTD correctness, why would we use round braces inside of round braces when declaring XML node?

Tags: xml, dtd

I'm looking at this piece of xml (inside of DTD file):

```
<!ELEMENT entry ((node1?, node2?, node3?), node4, node5?, (node6 | node16)?,
(node17, node18?, (node19, node20)?)*, node21?, node22?, node23*, node24*,
((node25) | (node26?, node27?))?, node28*, node29?, node30*, node31*)>
```

What is the reasoning behind having `(node1?, node2?, node3?)` in round braces?  Does that mean node1 and node2 and node3 are optional? -> but aren't they alreday optional by the fact that they have question mark added already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parentheses are used for grouping. Grouping lets you put qualifiers on parts of patterns, as with `(node6 | node16)?`, or to control precedence, as with `(node25) | (node26?, node27?)`. In the case of `(node1?, node2?, node3?)`, the parentheses are completely redundant. It means the same thing as `node1?, node2?, node3?`.

Sometimes people add extra parentheses because they think it makes things easier to read, or to emphasize related pieces of a pattern. Sometimes people just type too much for no good reason.